# [php]How to merge two muti dimensional array according to the values?

Tags: php

I have two array one is

```
$array1 = array(
    array("order"=>1111,"b"=>223332),
    array("order"=>2222,"b"=>123456)
);
```

the second is

```
$array2 = array(
    array("order"=>2222,"d"=>3333),
    array("order"=>1111,"d"=>44444)
);
```

result after merge

```
$array2 = array(
    array("order"=>2222,"d"=>3333,"b"=>123456),
    array("order"=>1111,"d"=>44444,"b"=>223332)
);
```

Now I can use loop to achiveve it  , but I want to know How to merge it with php function,

Answer (score 0):

Use array_merge_recursive method.